# How to write a Visual Studio Addin to manage comment annotations

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, plugins, comments, visual-studio-addins

I am new to Visual Studio addin development and want to create a small **prototype of an addin** for a course at the university. I already looked at a couple of tutorials and the VS SDK. Before I dig further into this topic, I want to ask if it is possible to develop what I want:

My goal (for the prototype is) to **receive all annotations in the sources commentary annotations** (i.e. TODO, HACK, FIXME, etc.) in my plugin and then to run some analytics.

So, is it (theoretically and using the existing API) possible to get a list of those commentary annotations? If yes, any link to a tutorial, blogpost or code sample would be very much appreciated!

**Thank** you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SVsTaskList service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286993.aspx) to access standard VS annotations. See also the following [EnumTaskItems sample](http://www.brandonkelly.com/post/2008/09/24/VSXtra-Visual-Studio-extensibility-for-the-rest-of-us.aspx).

Comment: Hi Sergey. Thank you very much for your post. This looks very promising. Unfortunately, I am unable to find out how to get a ServiceProvider (needed as the _serviceProvider variable in the example)... How can I do this? Thank you!!

Comment: In add-in you can get it from a DTE object: System.IServiceProvider _serviceProvider = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider((Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)dte);

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I basically had the same code, but didn't find the dte object (i.e. I oversaw that it was already present in the addin)... Have a great weekend!